# Why need the Code B to use SQLiteDatabase.() in input parameter?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is good,  in order to make it simply, somebody write the Code B.

I can't understand why the parameter shoud be `(transactionFun:SQLiteDatabase.()->Unit)` in Code B

I think  `(transactionFun: ()->Unit)` in Code B is good too, right?

**Code A**

```
fun excuteTransaction(transactionFun:()->Unit){
    val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    try{
        db.beginTransaction()
        transactionFun()
        db.setTransactionSuccessful()
    }finally {
        db.endTransaction()
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun SQLiteDatabase.executeTransaction(transactionFun:SQLiteDatabase.()->Unit){
    try{
        beginTransaction()
        transactionFun()
        setTransactionSuccessful()
    }finally {
        endTransaction()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code A** is good but to get access to your `dbHelper` you should declare a variable and send it to the lambda.
Code B is better because you have access to `dbHelper` without the variable because it is extension function. I think it is looking better.
For example, call **Code A** looks like

```
fun callCodeA() {
    excuteTransaction {
        dbHelper.execSQL("sone query")
    }
}
```

call **Code B** looks like

```
fun callCodeB() {
    dbHelper.executeTransaction {
        execSQL("sone query")
    }
}
```

Regarding `SQLiteDatabase.() -> Unit`. It needs to avoid variables and get access to `this`. Inside a lambda, you don't have access to the current object instance. The simplest way to achieve this is sending the current object to a lambda. For instance, you can do

```
fun SQLiteDatabase.executeTransaction(transactionFun: (SQLiteDatabase) -> Unit){
    try{
        beginTransaction()
        transactionFun(this)
        setTransactionSuccessful()
    }finally {
        endTransaction()
    }
}
```

but by using extension functions with lambdas it looks better.

Comment: Thanks! but what does SQLiteDatabase.() mean ?

Comment: @HelloCW I've edited the answer and added the explanation.